# mocha, node.js, ReferenceError: Board is not defined

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js

I'm new with node.js and I'm trying to collaborate in a project adding a mocha test suite for it. The issue that I have at the moment is the following

```
ReferenceError: Board is not defined
at new Game (/Users/.../dr_mojo/public/javascripts/game.js:8:20)
at Context.<anonymous> (/Users/.../dr_mojo/test/test.game.js:13:17)
at Test.Runnable.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:213:32)
at Runner.runTest (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:343:10)
at Runner.runTests.next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:389:12)
. . .
```

when run my test with

```
$> mocha -u tdd test/test.game.js --reporter spec
```

**public/javascripts/board.js**

```
function Board(width, height) {
  this.board = new Array(width);
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  for( var i = 0; i < width ; ++i) {
    this.board[i] = new Array(height);
  }
}
...
if(typeof module != 'undefined') {
  module.exports.Board = Board;
}
```

**public/javascripts/game.js**

```
function Game(lvl, speed, music) {
  this.initial = { ... };
  this.board = new Board(board_size[0], board_size[1]);
  ...
}
...
if(typeof module != 'undefined') {
  module.exports.Game = Game;
}
```

**test/test.game.js**

```
var assert = require("assert");
var Board  = require(__dirname + "/../public/javascripts/board.js").Board;
var Pill   = require(__dirname + "/../public/javascripts/pill.js").Pill;
var Game   = require(__dirname + "/../public/javascripts/game.js").Game;

describe('Game', function(){
  it('Clears a row', function(){
    var game  = new Game();
    var pill1 = new Pill(game.board, game.detector, [ {x : 0 , y : 0 }, {x : 1, y : 0 } ],["red", "red"]);
    var pill2 = new Pill(game.board, game.detector, [ {x : 2 , y : 0 }, {x : 3, y : 0 } ],["red", "red"]);

    assert.equal(game.board.matches().length, 1);

    game.findMatches(function(){});
    assert.equal(game.board.matches().length, 0);
  })
})
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
    port    = 8888;

var app = express.createServer();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set("view engine", "jade");
app.set('view options', { layout: false });

app.get('/play', function(req, res){
  res.render('play_game');
});

app.listen(port);
```

As you can see the error is in `game.js:8` the thing is that I don't know how to configure it properly given that when the game is playing it works ok, this means that `new Game()` works ok and the problem is that I'm not configuring it properly from the test suite. I'll appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you provided my guess is that you'll need to `require` board.js from game.js like so:

```
var Board  = require(__dirname + "/../public/javascripts/board.js").Board;
```

It looks like this is a browser game that you're also testing from node.js. Is that correct?